# how to pass more than one value in pushpage method of onsen ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, onsen-ui

Hello I am a newbie in angulajs and javasript and I am making a demo of passing values in **`pushpage`** function of **onsen ui**. I have succeeded in passing only one value in push page but while I am trying to pass two values its not passing, so can anybody please help me to resolve this issue, I have tried as below:

**(inside controller)**

```
var Content = ' ';
            var resid = ' ';
            var catname = ' '
           var options, 
         elem,
         obj = {};  


            for (i = 0 ; i< data ['Details'].length ; i++)
            { 
               resid=  + data['Details'][i]['intGlCode'] ;
                 catname   = data['Details'][i]['varName'];      

obj['params'] = resid;
obj['params1'] =  catname;
options = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(options);
elem = "<li class='list__item list__item--chevron' onclick=gallery.pushPage('list-page.html', "+options+");>"; 
console.log(elem);
                if (Content === ' ')
                {
                    //{params:'+resid+',params1 : '+catname+'}

                    Content =elem+
//    '<li class="list__item list__item--chevron" onclick=gallery.pushPage("list-page.html", { params: '+resid+' });>'+

 '<ons-icon class="ons-icon ons-icon--ion ion-android-restaurant fa-lg" fixed-width="true" icon='+data['Details'][i]['varIcon']+'>'+'</ons-icon>'
```

Comment: Please provide a plunker

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the **[`pushPage()`](http://onsen.io/reference/ons-navigator.html#method-pushPage)** parameter object first using the bracket notation that allows you to inject the attributes values. O
Once the object is created you can then parse that as a string that you concatenate with the string in the controller. The following demonstrated this

```
var options, 
    elem,
    obj = {},     
    resid = 'foo',
    catname = 'bar';
obj['params'] = resid;
obj['params1'] =  catname;
options = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(options);
elem = "<li class='list__item list__item--chevron' onclick=gallery.pushPage('list-page.html', "+options+");>";
console.log(elem); /* prints <li class='list__item list__item--chevron' onclick=gallery.pushPage('list-page.html', {"params":"foo","params1":"bar"});> */
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var options, 
    elem,
    obj = {},     
    resid = 'foo',
    catname = 'bar';
obj['params'] = resid;
obj['params1'] =  catname;
options = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(options);
elem = "<li class='list__item list__item--chevron' onclick=gallery.pushPage('list-page.html', "+options+");>";

pre.innerHTML = elem;
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: hello,now i am getting this error `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
 

gallery.pushPage('list-page.html' `..pls see my update on question.

Comment: You may have missed a comma in your code `... onclick=gallery.pushPage('list-page.html' "+options+");>";` should be `... onclick=gallery.pushPage('list-page.html', "+options+");>";`

Comment: hello thanks sir,it still gives me error of "end of script".

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to put it in the param value. Note that you need a php file that provides the json data.

Page one

```
<ons-row ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('page2.html', {param1: x.param1, param2: x.param2})">
   <ons-col width="35px">
     <i class="fa fa-stethoscope fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </ons-col>
   <ons-col>
    <div class="timeline-from">
      <span class="timeline-name">{{ x.param1 }}</span>
    </div>
  </ons-col>
</ons-row>
```

and on the controller

```
//Pushed Page Controller

app.controller('PushedPageController', function($scope){
  var options = $scope.myNavigator.getCurrentPage().options;
  $scope.x = options.param1;
$scope.options = options;
})
```

and on page2.html

```
<ons-list class="timeline" modifier="inset" ng-controller="PushedPageController">
 <ons-list-item class="timeline-li" modifier="tappable"  ng-repeat="a in x">
  <ons-row>
   <ons-col>
     <div class="timeline-from">
        <span class="timeline-name">{{ a.first }}</span>
     </div>
     <div class="timeline-message" >
         {{ a.second }}
     </div>
   </ons-col>
  </ons-row>
 </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```